# is ellipse inside ellipse in WGS84 ellipsoid

Tags: wgs84, ellipsoid

My question is quite clear:

Assume that there is an ellipse, namely EL1. Parameters of the ellipsoid are (focus11 [latitude, longitude], focus12[latitude, longitude], radius1).

And a second ellipse, namely EL2. Which is defined with the same parameter set (focus21 [latitude, longitude], focus22[latitude, longitude], radius2).

The reference ellipsoid is WGS84.

What is the method to find if EL1 contains EL2 ?

So far the best approach I come up with is to convert the EL1 and EL2 to polygons. But it is quite costly.

Is there any idea? 
Any help is appriciated.
Waiting for your replys ...

Comment: I think your parameters for  EL1 and EL2 are incomplete. Two foci and a radius don't seem to be enough information to determine and ellipse. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @r.k. The two focii & radius implicitly give the semi-major & semi-minor axis. Hence the ellipse is fully defined.

Comment: @OP Are you assuming the ellipse is on a flat surface, or is the earth's curveture important in your calculations?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I'm a bit confused as to where the radius would be centered at. The foci? If so, aren't two focal radii(with different values) needed? An illustration would be most helpful I think. I hope the OP will reply soon.

Comment: @R.K. Look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ellipse_Properties_of_Directrix_and_String_Construction.svg If you have F1 & F2, and radius (I guess that means a) you can get the center(which is inbetween F1 & F2), and then you can calculate e, and then get the semi-minor axis

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Oh... thanks for the conics lesson. It's been a while since I had one. :)

Comment: @OP: contained fully or do partial intersections count as well? What are you actually working with? An obvious optimisation is to first compare their bounding box' coordinates, like most GIS software does.

Comment: Hi, The ellipse is on an ellipsoid of WGS84 so the curvature of earth is important and it is defined.

Comment: @lynxlynxlyn I could not follow the path you proposed. Do you mean to define a rectangle, minimum rectangle to cover the ellipse than compare these rectangles? If so this method will not be correct.

Comment: The question is quite *unclear*. Ellipses are *Euclidean* figures and do not have a universal meaning in Riemannian manifolds like the WGS 84 ellipsoid. The idea does generalize--but it depends on how you characterize an "ellipse".  Is it a locus of points whose sum of distances to two foci is a constant? Or is it the locus of points whose distances to a focus and (geodesic) directrix are in a constant ratio? Or perhaps is it the locus of points equidistant to a focus and a circular directrix? Or a curve that reflects all geodesics from one focus towards another focus? Or something else?

Comment: Hmmm... I am confused will all the possibilities you mentioned. To clarify what I mean by ellipse on an ellipsoid I will use your definition **`it is a locus of points whose sum of distances to two foci is a constant`** and  **the sum is equal to radius of the ellipse** .